# Subspace of a separable metric space and the definition of basis of metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space. A family $(G_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L}$
> of *nonempty* open sets of $E$ is called a **basis** for the open sets
> of the metric space $E$ if every nonempty open set of $E$ is the union
> of a subfamily of the family $(G_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L}$.

Suppose $(E, d)$ is separable and $\emptyset\ne F\subset E$. Then there exists an at most countable basis $(G_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L}$ for the open sets of $E$. I want to show that $F$ is separable. The idea is to show that $(F\cap G_\lambda)_\lambda$ is basis for $F$ but how can I ensure that $F\cap G_\lambda\ne\emptyset$ for all $\lambda\in L$? If $G_\lambda\cap F=\emptyset$ for some $\lambda\in L$, then $(G_\lambda\cap F)_\lambda$ is not a basis according to my definition.

Comment: Note that empty set is also open.

Comment: Correct; but my definition of basis requires that $G_\lambda\ne\emptyset$ for all $\lambda\in L$..

Comment: Then neglect those $\lambda$ for which $F\cap G_\lambda=\emptyset$. Then you can again do, as subset of countable set is at most countable.

Comment: Can we ensure that there exists at least one $\lambda\in L$ such that $F\cap G_\lambda\ne\emptyset$?

Comment: As long as $F\not=\emptyset$ there always such $\lambda$.

Comment: Let $F\not=\emptyset$ then choose $x\in F$. Now the set $B(x,1):=\{y\in E:d(x,y)<1\}$ is open in $E$ and $B(x,1)\cap F\not=\emptyset$.

Comment: Got it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define, if $\mathcal{B}$ is the at most countable base for $E$ and $F$ is a subspace:

$$\mathcal{B}_F:=\{B \cap F\mid B \in \mathcal{B} \land B \cap F \neq \emptyset \}$$

This collection is also at most countable (one or no set is present for each member of $\mathcal{B}$) and consists of relatively open subsets of $F$. If $O$ is open in $F$ and $x \in O$, then for some open $O'$ of $E$ we have $O' \cap F=O$ and so as $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $E$ we have $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq O'$. But then $$x \in B_x \cap F \subseteq O' \cap F=O$$ and $B_x \cap F \in \mathcal{B}_F$ by definition. So $\mathcal{B}_F$ is a base for $F$.